# Understanding the x86 idivl instruction

Tags: assembly, x86

Description of this instruction is:

```
Signed divide EDX:EAX by DWORD byte (EAX=Quo, EDX=Rem)
```

I don't understand what `:` means here? Whats the meaning of `EDX:EAX`?

Comment: it is a 64 bit number upper bits are EDX lower are EAX

Comment: its a 64 bit number divided by a 32 bit number and then you get a 32 bit quotient and 32 bit remainder.

Comment: To add to the above comments, in case it wasn't obvious, `idivl` = `i` - integer (signed), `div` - divide, `l` - long.  Divides a long (64-bit) signed integer.

Comment: are you creating [2 accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12822199/josh) just for asking 2 questions?

Comment: From the [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual](https://software.intel.com/en-us/download/intel-64-and-ia-32-architectures-sdm-combined-volumes-1-2a-2b-2c-2d-3a-3b-3c-3d-and-4): *3.7.2 Register Operands: [...] Some instructions (such as the DIV and MUL instructions) use quadword operands contained in a pair of 32-bit registers. **Register pairs are represented with a colon separating them.** For example, in the register pair EDX:EAX, EDX contains the high order bits and EAX contains the low order bits of a quadword operand.*

Answer (score 2):

Following the comment from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60012458/why-idivl-uses-edxeax-instead-of-a-64-bit-register)

> Because the instruction was introduced on a 32-bit architecture. It
>   divides a 64-bit value in `EDX:EAX` by a 32-bit value, the result is
>   stored in `EAX` for the Quotient, and `EDX` for the Remainder. On the
>   32-bit architecture there were no 64-bit registers like `RAX`

See comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60012458/why-idivl-uses-edxeax-instead-of-a-64-bit-register)

Comment: The links are broken.